# Ruby on Rails Devise Always localhost: 3000 will be redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I accessed `localhost/3000/login_users/sign_up` and registered a user.
After that, I accessed `localhost/3000/login_users/sign_in`. However, it will always be redirected to `localhost:3000`.

I will post *routes.rb*.  [I will post the serverlog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLcwd.png)
Why is that?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :login_users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file,
  # see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Maybe you're being redirected because you are already logged in?

Comment: I do not sign_in. I just sign up.

Comment: @kuri sign_up automatically sign in the user

Comment: Could you please add server logs for sign_in action?

Comment: Devise comes with a `confirmable` module: [How To: Add :confirmable to Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users)

Comment: I posted serverlog.

Comment: Look at the line 'Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication' - it tells that the user is already logged in

Comment: I understood that login was done.
I will try ``` How To: Add: confirmable to Users`` you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect user to a specific path after sign in by defining a method in application controller.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
  some_path
end
```

by default devise redirect to root path. you can set a root path is routes.rb also as following:

```
 root :to => 'testers#index'
```